# SharePoint Online SSO Map driver throws error when user change password

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, webdav, sso

A week ago I roll out this solution [automatically map your SPO Document Library](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/OneDriveMapper-automaticall-d7d498b0/view/Discussions) .

Everything was smooth until i changed the password of the user account.
Now I get the error :

> Mapping target: \xxxx-my.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\personal\xxx_xxxx_xxx_xxx\Documents
>   failed to contact O: after mapping it to \xxxxxsharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\Documents, check if the URL is valid. Error: 
>   Access Denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first add the web site to your trusted sites list, browse to the web site, and select the option to login automatically.

So I am in the middle of troubleshooting I got the conclusion the workaround is 
either Sync the library or open the document library with explorer, manually.

[image]

I am looking for a PowerShell that at least launch the sync application or "Open with Explorer"[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think when you need to rerun the powershell script again to remap with the current credentials as the old mapping is using the old password, renmapping with the ps code should fix the issue.

Comment: I did several times, as well I synchronized the AD sync tool password.
Yet not changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I turn on fiddler and start to analyze the WEBdav traffic, I noticed the frames which try to connect with O365 missed the **FedAuth** and **rtFa** parameter in the Headers/cookie.

Armed the next [Open source solution](http://fabiocuneaz.blogspot.no/2015/03/new-cookie-365-release-hi-all-i-am.html#comment-form) , 
I was able to fix the problem and keep stable my Disk mapping, bypassing the cookies issue.

Another important thing are

- To keep regular password synchronizations towards Azure.
- Keep free of error Download Center and OneDrive For Business client.
- Implement different GPO that keep the SSO and cokkie freshness.